# Can you lock the tips of hair particles for hair dynamics?

Tags: hair

I have created hair for a model i have been working on. Its style is a messy/lose ponytale using a couple different hair particle system. The ponytale is its own hair particle system. The rest of the hair ends where the hair band is supposed to be:

[image]

Now i have been playing around with the hair dynamics a bit, but i'm running in some issue. The tips (where the hair band is supposed to be) needs to stay in place, while the rest of the hair should be movable from the hair dynamics. So i'm wondering is it possible to lock the tips of the hair particles in place?

Thanks